# how to install VirtualBox 6.0.6 for mint Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, linux-mint

I downloaded virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb. When I tired `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_bionic_amd64.deb` it fails by the following errors:

> dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.0 (--install):  dependency
>   problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for systemd
>   (229-4ubuntu21) ... Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19)
>   ... Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
>   Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22+linuxmint1) ...
>   Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ... Processing
>   triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ... Processing
>   triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ... Errors were
>   encountered while processing:

**Updated   Question**
I tried this 
    cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
So I downloaded virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb. Then tried `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb`
I got error:-
(Reading database ... 226145 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking virtualbox-6.0 (6.0.6-130049~Ubuntu~xenial) over (6.0.6-130049~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-6.0:
     virtualbox-6.0 depends on libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2); however:
      Package libcurl3 is not installed.

```
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-6.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.0
```

How do I install it?

Comment: You should download the Virtualbox version for the Ubuntu version your Mint is based on.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Pls check updated question

Answer (score 1):

You should install the dependencies that the error quotes (libcurl3 and possibly others). Because of the fact that you are not installing virtualbox via apt (the primary package manager) those are not installed automatically and you have to do it manually. You can do it by typing:

```
sudo apt install libcurl3 [eventual-other-packages]
```

And retrying with `dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb`.

You can also try to make them installed automatically by typing

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

after getting your error (with `dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.6-130049_Ubuntu_xenial_amd64.deb`).

In the first version of your question there was also a compatibility problem (virtualbox for Ubuntu 18 instead of 16) but i see you already solved that.